# TSQL: First instance of X

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I need to get all the `Room_IDs` where the `Occupancy` are reported first time vacant, so only if the last instance of the `Occupancy` is vacant and consecutively has been without interruption during the life of a `Room_ID` in relationship to the `InspectionDate` *(excluding for example occupied > vacant > occupied > vacant or vacant > occupied or vacant > occupied > vacant > vacant but including vacant > vacant)*

This is a simplified table I am using as an example:

```
 Room_Id    inspection_ID   Occupancy InspectionDate
 ----------------------------------------------------
   1        11              vacant       5/15/2015
   1        12              occupied     5/21/2015
   1        13              vacant       9/19/2015
   1        14              occupied     1/16/2016
   2        21              vacant       3/25/2015
   2        22              occupied     8/27/2015
   2        23              occupied     4/17/2016
   3        31              occupied    12/12/2015
   3        32              occupied     3/22/2015
   3        33              vacant        2/2/2016
   3        34              occupied     3/24/2016
   4        41              occupied     4/17/2015
   4        42              occupied    11/12/2015
   4        43              occupied    12/22/2015
   4        44              vacant        2/2/2016
   4        45              vacant       3/24/2016
   5        45              vacant       3/24/2015
   5        45              vacant       3/24/2016
```

My result should look like this:

```
 Room_Id    inspection_ID   Occupancy InspectionDate
 ---------------------------------------------------
   4        41              occupied     4/17/2015
   4        42              occupied    11/12/2015
   4        43              occupied    12/22/2015
   4        44              vacant        2/2/2016
   4        45              vacant       3/24/2016
   5        45              vacant       3/23/2015
   5        45              vacant       3/24/2016
```

Please let me know if it is not clear enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TSQL : the top records of a given partition (conditional)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38112133/tsql-the-top-records-of-a-given-partition-conditional)

Comment: @AlexKudryashev close, but not quite the same, that one sees if the 2 last records are vacant for every instance of the ID .. this one checks for FTVs

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from T where Room_ID in (    
    select Room_ID from T
    group by Room_ID
    having
          coalesce(
              max(case when occupancy = 'occupied' then InspectionDate end),
              cast('19000101' as date)
          ) <
          min(case when occupancy = 'vacant' then InspectionDate end)
);
```

If the `having` condition is true then all of the vacants appear later than the occupieds (or a dummy date when none are present.)

Here's the same approach using analytics:

```
select * from
( 
    select *,
        max(case when occupancy = 'occupied' then InspectionDate end)
            over (partition by Room_ID, occupancy) as max_o
        min(case when occupancy = 'vacant'   then InspectionDate end)
            over (partition by Room_ID, occupancy) as min_v
    from T
) t
where max_o < min_v or max_o is null and max_v is not null;
```

Check the plans and see which one works out better.